# Renaming many factors to a new, same factor name in R

Tags: r

I'm working with some data from a restaurant for a personal project.  The way the data is organized, there are table number labels, and also to-go order names.  I'd like to change all of the to-go order names to the same label of "togo" while maintaining all the table numbers.

Example:

```
> chknum <- seq(1:10)
> Tble <- c("1","5","12","Togo", "Bob togo","Cheesecake togo","Togo in 15 mins", "To go", "To-go","4")
> data.frame(chknum,Tble)
   chknum            Tble
1       1               1
2       2               5
3       3              12
4       4            Togo
5       5        Bob togo
6       6 Cheesecake togo
7       7 Togo in 15 mins
8       8           To go
9       9           To-go
10     10               4
```

And Ideally I'd like all of the togo orders to have the same label:

```
> 
> togo <- c("1","5","12",rep("Togo",6),"4")
> data.frame(chknum,togo)
   chknum togo
1       1    1
2       2    5
3       3   12
4       4 Togo
5       5 Togo
6       6 Togo
7       7 Togo
8       8 Togo
9       9 Togo
10     10    4
```

I've tried factor(x) and renaming in all the ways I know how, but there are hundreds of different togo order name factors and I'm not sure of the most efficient way.

Comment: As an aside, don't use `cbind` to make a dataset because it converts everything to text. Use `data.frame(chknum,togo)`

Comment: Could you do it by exclusion? Anything that is not just digits is "to go"?

Answer (score 2):

We can just convert it to `numeric` to get all NA elements for non-numeric elements and replace it with 'Togo'

```
df1$Tble[is.na(as.numeric(df1$Tble))] <- "Togo"
df1
#   chknum Tble
#1       1    1
#2       2    5
#3       3   12
#4       4 Togo
#5       5 Togo
#6       6 Togo
#7       7 Togo
#8       8 Togo
#9       9 Togo
#10     10    4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(chknum,Tble, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try regular expressions,

```
chknum <- seq(1:10)
Tble <- c("1","5","12","Togo", "Bob togo","Cheesecake togo","Togo in 15 mins", "To go", "To-go","4")
Tble[grepl("[Tt][Oo].*[Gg][Oo]", Tble)] <- "Togo"
cbind(chknum, Tble)
```

Here the expression `"[Tt][Oo].*[Gg][Oo]"` means "Any capitalisation of 'to' followed by 'anything' followed by any capitalisation of 'go'". Basically to catch any variation you might see. It's quite liberal so it'll catch something like "tomato goose".

Comment: probably `.*` is too liberal as you intimate... maybe start with `[ -]*` and expand from there instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)

# grab the numerics first. must be digits (\\d) from beginning(^) to end($). 
# replace with what was found in first between parentheses ie. dont modify
# thsi isnt strictly necessary but left to show how to match numerics.
df$togo <- str_replace(trimws(df$Tble), "^(\\d+)$", "\\1")

# grab any string beginning with to, separated by one or more spaces(\\s) or one or more dashes((\\-)), and ending in go. Ignore case (?i)
# capture the whole string, but replace with "Togo"
df$togo <- str_replace(trimws(df$Tble), "(?i)(.*to(\\s|\\-)*go.*)", "Togo")
df

# chknum            Tble togo
# 1       1               1    1
# 2       2               5    5
# 3       3              12   12
# 4       4            Togo Togo
# 5       5        Bob togo Togo
# 6       6 Cheesecake togo Togo
# 7       7 Togo in 15 mins Togo
# 8       8           To go Togo
# 9       9           To-go Togo
# 10     10               4    4
```

Comment: Hey epi99,  thanks for the great answer.  Using (\\d) to indicate any digit is a new concept to me.  Is there an equivalent procedure for any letter or word?  There are also to-go orders that dont contain the letters "to",  such as "Jeff" and I was wondering if there was something like (\\word) to do the same procedure as the digits, but with any letter/word

Comment: @SDMcLean13, these are character classes in regex. Try http://www.regexr.com/ . Click  Reference, then Character Classes